# Does go test run unit tests concurrently?

Tags: unit-testing, go

When `go test` is ran it runs your files ending in `_test.go` by running the functions that start in the format `TestXxx` and use the (*t testing.T) module. I was wondering if each function in the `_test.go` file were ran concurrently or if it definitively ran each function separately? Does it create a go routine for each one? If it does create a go routine for each one, can I monitor the go routines in some way? Is it ever possible to do something like `golibrary.GoRoutines()` and get an instance for each one and monitor them some how or something like that?

---

Note: this question assumes you using the testing framework that comes with go (testing).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: so this is the thing...each TestXXX function I have creates a process that connects with some port number. It would be weird if all of them tried to connect to same port or did something weird like that. I want to control the port number they connect to and make it unique through some atomic incremented or terminate each process so that I never need more than one different port number. I am also curious now to know how to monitor go-routines however.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Yes**, [tests are executed as goroutines](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/182bdbb1e1d62fe53f8386e7b02c7738898d373b/src/testing/testing.go#L555) and, thus, executed **concurrently**.

However, tests do **not run in parallel by default** as pointed out by [@jacobsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375966/does-go-test-run-unit-tests-concurrently/24376644?noredirect=1#comment45305870_24376644). To enable parallel execution you would have to call `t.Parallel()` in your test case and set `GOMAXPROCS` appropriately or supply `-parallel N` (which is set to `GOMAXPROCS` by default).

The simplest solution for your case when running tests in parallel would be to have a global slice for port numbers and a global atomically incremented index that serves as association between test and port from the slice. That way you control the port numbers and have one port for each test. Example:

```
import "sync/atomic"

var ports [...]uint64 = {10, 5, 55}
var portIndex uint32

func nextPort() uint32 {
    return atomic.AddUint32(&portIndex, 1)
}
```

Comment: I could also make a single global lock (or channel), that makes all the go-routines freeze, except for the one that is suppose to run. That way, I don't have to ever use a different port number (which is good that way if the number of tests increases dramatically, I do not have to worry what port number I use). Though, it does reduce concurrency...

Comment: btw, kudos on looking at the src of the testing.go, it wouldn't have occurred to me to look there. Now I learned, to look into the go src to find out answers to this type of question. Thnx! :)

Comment: I think you missed that tests may be run concurrently only if they call `t.Parallel`.

Comment: @jacobsa No, they're executed in parallel when you do that. But I will update my answer for clarity.

Comment: Note that the `go test ./...` runs the tests for _different packages_ in parallel by default, unless the `-p 1` is passed to it.

Comment: it's not necessary define parallel flag in test run command, as said manual:  "by default, it is set to the value of GOMAXPROCS".
Whole description is:
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4df662fb373480b5055e645120558bb536fae42c/src/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go#L250

Comment: @KonstantinYaniv correct, this is why I said you need to set `GOMAXPROCS` accordingly. This, however, does not make tests run in parallel. You still need to call `t.Parallel()`.

Comment: To be honest, I find the wording in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4df662fb373480b5055e645120558bb536fae42c/src/cmd/go/internal/test/test.go#L250 very confusing. I don't know if by "default" they mean "if you don't specify this flag at all" or if they mean "if you specify this flag but without an explicit value after the flag name". Here in the answers you can find some people saying that you "need to specify the `-parallel` flag", which adds to confusion, since this seems to imply we can use the flag without specifying a value. A clarification on this would be nice.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, as other answers already pointed, tests inside one _test.go file are running in parallel only if you add `t.Parallel()` and run with `-parallel` tag.

BUT - by default the command `go test` runs in parallel tests for different packages, and default is the number of CPUs available (see `go help build`)

So to disable parallel execution you should run tests like this
`go test -p 1 ./...`

Answer (score 12):

Yes if you add this :
t.Parallel() to your functions.

like this:

```
func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    //your test code here

}
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two aspects of "parallel tests" in go.

1. Testing of packages (folders) in parallel. Controlled by `-p` flag.

`go help build`:

```
    -p n
        the number of programs, such as build commands or
        test binaries, that can be run in parallel.
        The default is GOMAXPROCS, normally the number of CPUs available.
```

2. Testing of tests within a package. Controlled by `-parallel` flag, and tests need this enabled with `t.Parallel()`.

`go help testflag`:

```
    -parallel n
        Allow parallel execution of test functions that call t.Parallel.
        The value of this flag is the maximum number of tests to run
        simultaneously; by default, it is set to the value of GOMAXPROCS.
        Note that -parallel only applies within a single test binary.
        The 'go test' command may run tests for different packages
        in parallel as well, according to the setting of the -p flag
        (see 'go help build').
```

For #1, you can observe this directly by having tests in multiple packages, and forcing them to be long running with a sleep. Then ps aux and grep for go running and you'll see separate processes in parallel.

Or run with `-x` detail flag. That pretty clearly shows what’s going on. The tests are launched once per package (e.g. given have *_test.go files in several package. Note I’m running `go test -x ./... -v -count=1 |& ruby -pe 'print Time.now.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ")' |& tee  temp.out`  with various configurations of -p=N -parallel=M, you can see in parallel them running:

```
[2022-05-09 17:22:26] $WORK/b065/understandinit.test -test.paniconexit0 -test.timeout=10m0s -test.parallel=1 -test.v=true -test.count=1
[2022-05-09 17:22:26] $WORK/b001/main.test -test.paniconexit0 -test.timeout=10m0s -test.parallel=1 -test.v=true -test.count=1
[2022-05-09 17:22:26] $WORK/b062/mainsub.test -test.paniconexit0 -test.timeout=10m0s -test.parallel=1 -test.v=true -test.count=1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run them concurrently by flagging the test with [t.Parallel](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Parallel)
and then run the test using the `-parallel` flag.

You can see [other testing flags here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Testing_flags)